# Validation in Yup React based on the value of checkbox

Tags: javascript, reactjs, yup, react-hook-form

I am building a form in React using [React-form-hook](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-hook-form) and validation using yup.

I am using a watch() to check if the checkbox is clicked or not and if it is clicked it will display another input field in the form which was not visible before.

Even when I haven't clicked the checkbox which means that refer input field is not visible or rendered, it still does not perform the handlesubmit.

I can't think of a way to get around this.

```
   <div className="form-check">
      <input type="checkbox" id="askRefer" {...register("askRefer")} />
      <label className="form-check-label" htmlFor="askRefer">
        Refered ?
      </label>
   </div>

  {referedStatus && (
      <div className="form-group">
        <label htmlFor="referedNumber">Refereed Number</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          className="form-control"
          placeholder="refer number"
          {...register("refer")}
        />
        {errors.refer && (
          <p className="error-message">{errors.refer.message}</p>
        )}
      </div>
    )}
```

**Validation code in yup.**

```
const valSchema = yup.object().shape({
    email: yup.string()
          .required("email is required")
          .email("only accepts an email"),
    password: yup.string().required("password cannot be empty"),
    confirmPassword: yup.string()
           .required("confirmation of password is important")
           .oneOf([yup.ref("password"), null], "password doesn't match"),
    refer:yup.number()
             .required("please input refer number")
             .positive("entry should be greater than 0")
             .integer("input integer value"))
   });
```

**Reat-hook-form:**

```
 const {register, handleSubmit, watch, formState: { errors }} = useForm({
                                                        resolver: yupResolver(valSchema),
                                                        mode: "onTouched",
                                                        });
let referedStatus= watch("askRefer", false);
```

***If it helps, the complete code is here:***

```js
import React from "react";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import { yupResolver } from "@hookform/resolvers/yup";
import * as yup from "yup";

function Rform() {


  const valSchema = yup.object().shape({
    email: yup
      .string()
      .required("email is required")
      .email("only accepts an email"),
    password: yup.string().required("password cannot be empty"),
    confirmPassword: yup
      .string()
      .required("confirmation of password is important")
      .oneOf([yup.ref("password"), null], "password doesn't match"),
    refer:(yup
      .number()
      .required("please input refer number")
      .positive("entry should be greater than 0")
      .integer("input integer value"))
  });

  console.log(valSchema)

  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    watch,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useForm({
    resolver: yupResolver(valSchema),
    mode: "onTouched",
  });

let referedStatus= watch("askRefer", false);

  const onSubmit = (formData) => {
    let url = "http://localhost:4000/things/register";
    fetch(url, {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
      body: JSON.stringify(formData)
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((result) => console.log(result));
  };
  console.log(referedStatus);

  return (
    <div className="container" onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      <form>
        <div className="form-group">
          <label>Email address</label>
          <input
            className="form-control"
            aria-describedby="emailHelp"
            placeholder="Enter email"
            {...register("email")}
          />
          <small className="form-text text-muted">
                We don't share the credential.
          </small>
          {errors.email && (
            <p className="error-message">{errors.email.message}</p>
          )}
        </div>
        <div className="form-group">
          <label>Password</label>
          <input
            type="password"
            className="form-control"
            placeholder="Password"
            {...register("password")}
          />
          {errors.password && (
            <p className="error-message">{errors.password.message}</p>
          )}
        </div>

        <div className="form-group">
          <label>Password</label>
          <input
            type="password"
            className="form-control"
            placeholder="Password"
            {...register("confirmPassword")}
          />
          {errors.confirmPassword && (
            <p className="error-message">{errors.confirmPassword.message}</p>
          )}
        </div>

        <div className="form-check">
          <input type="checkbox" id="askRefer" {...register("askRefer")} />
          <label className="form-check-label" htmlFor="askRefer">
            Refered ?
          </label>
        </div>

        {referedStatus && (
          <div className="form-group">
            <label htmlFor="referedNumber">Refereed Number</label>
            <input
              type="text"
              className="form-control"
              placeholder="refer number"
              {...register("refer")}
            />
            {errors.refer && (
              <p className="error-message">{errors.refer.message}</p>
            )}
          </div>
        )}

        <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">
          Submit
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Rform;
```

This is what form looks like in the browser.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the optional field "refer" (as long as "askRefer" is `false`) is required in your yup schema. You have to add your "askRefer" checkbox to the yup schema and then you can check via the `when` method, to set validation for "refer" if "askRefer" is `true`.

```js
const valSchema = yup.object().shape({
  email: yup
    .string()
    .required("email is required")
    .email("only accepts an email"),
  password: yup.string().required("password cannot be empty"),
  confirmPassword: yup
    .string()
    .required("confirmation of password is important")
    .oneOf([yup.ref("password"), null], "password doesn't match"),
  askRefer: yup.boolean(),
  refer: yup.number().when("askRefer", {
    is: true,
    then: yup
      .number()
      .required("please input refer number")
      .positive("entry should be greater than 0")
      .integer("input integer value")
  })
});
```

[image: Edit React Hook Form - Basic (forked)]

Comment: Thank you, I wish there is a blog or article or videos with the most used yup validation method listed.

Comment: In addition to that, I dont understand why for value comparison with a sibling with oneOf need the second parameter to be null  ----> oneOf([yup.ref("password"), null]. Can you help me understand the logic behind it.

Comment: I think you can omit `null` as it has no benefit in your use case -> [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-yup-optional-field--without-null-lkm16). You would use `null` if you want the check to accept nullable values. I found out, that there was this GitHub issue with `oneOf` that it wasn't possible to use the `nullable`method. Check this [comment](https://github.com/jquense/yup/issues/104#issuecomment-670442387). Where do you found the information that `null` is needed?

Comment: Unfortunately, i'm not aware of any articles regarding the most used yup validation methods, but i found the docs in the GitHub repo quite useful as there are all methods explained in detail.